# Update 'meta_value' from wp_usermeta table assigning value of another 'meta_value' of the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, select, subquery

I apologize for confusing and cumbersome question, but anyway I need to do following: In 'wp_usermeta' table I have fields (meta_keys) 'category' and 'request_category' for all users. Now I want overwrite meta_value of 'category' with meta_value 'request_category' where 'category' has a specific value.

But after executing SQL query I'm getting NULL in 'meta_value' fields of 'category'. Here is my code:

```
UPDATE 
  wp_usermeta
SET
  wp_usermeta.meta_value = 
  (SELECT 
    umeta_tmp.meta_value 
  FROM
    umeta_tmp
  WHERE umeta_tmp.meta_key = 'request_category' 
    AND umeta_tmp.umeta_id = wp_usermeta.umeta_id) 
WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'category' 
  AND wp_usermeta.meta_value = 'travel_agency'
```

Where table 'umeta_tmp' is a temporary table where I kept data of 'wp_usermeta' table (since I can't modify the same table which I use in the SELECT part).

Could anyone hint me how can I achieve that.
Thanks.

Comment: would something like update_user_meta not work for this?

Comment: Yep, I can use that as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert into UPDATE with JOIN

```
UPDATE wp_usermeta
JOIN umeta_tmp ON umeta_tmp.meta_key = 'request_category' 
               AND umeta_tmp.umeta_id = wp_usermeta.umeta_id
SET wp_usermeta.meta_value = umeta_tmp.meta_value
WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'category' AND 
      wp_usermeta.meta_value = 'travel_agency'`
```

If the `umeta_tmp` table is just the copy from the `wp_usermeta` table then the `JOIN` and `WHERE` conditions are contradictious because you want the `meta_key` field of the same row (equalization by `id`) to be `'request_category'` in the `umeta_tmp` table and at the same time to be `'category'` in the `wp_usermeta`.
Having this in view and moving the `WHERE` condition into the `JOIN` the result will be the following:

```
UPDATE wp_usermeta
JOIN umeta_tmp ON wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'category' AND 
               wp_usermeta.meta_value = 'travel_agency' AND
               umeta_tmp.umeta_id = wp_usermeta.umeta_id
SET wp_usermeta.meta_value = umeta_tmp.meta_value
```